# Is there a case-sensitivity difference in PHP regarding browser?

Tags: php, google-chrome, internet-explorer, case-sensitive

The weirdest thing happened to my coworker while refactoring some code of a project he didn't develop himself :
While checking the value of a **$_GET** key, he has different results **depending on the browser he uses for his testing**.

The value he was testing was **$_GET['validation']**. When initialized, **'validation'** is in lowercase.

However, the project developer called **$_GET['Validation']** on the testing code.

If the project is accessed with **Google Chrome**, there is a PHP error saying that the "Validation" key doesn't exist in **$_GET**.
**BUT**, if he uses **Internet Explorer**, the check is performed and everything works...

How the hell is that possible ? I thought array keys were case-sensitive ?!

Thanks a lot in advance, for any information you can provide :)

Comment: Yes, array keys are case sensitive in PHP. But PHP creates $_GET, based on what data is passed from the client. So the browsers must be sending different data to begin with here then, so you’d need to start looking at what is going on on the _client_ side.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your response. I will check how $_GET is created. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, key names are case sensitive. But you could transform all keys to lower case for convenience.